# Is it poor practice to have empty indexes in a C# array?

Tags: c#

I have a 2D Array in C# that holds the data of hundreds of objects. If the array index values I am using for the filled data start at a value larger than 0, leaving the indexes before it blank, am I losing performance on all of the empty array spaces?

For example if I have an array:

```
Object[,] objectArray = new Object[1000, 1000];
```

And I fill indexes x: 500-999 && y:500-999 with Objects, and leave the indexes 0-499 empty, am I losing performance or memory or is it negligible.

I may need the indexes in the future as the program runs but during most of the program's life they will be empty. (For context, the empty spaces are for tiles a player in a game may explore, using the index as coordinates)

Should I just create a new array and fill it when needed?

Edited to be more specific to my case.

Comment: This is literally the issue that `List<T>` fixes. Why not use a list?

Comment: Poor practice (actually, a very bad practice) is using `object` instead of a specific type. Empty indexes like this are a waste of memory *unless* there's a chance they will be needed. In this case, they will. Which leaves the bad practice of using `object`

Comment: It all depends on which operations you're performing on the array. Every scan through the array will have scan through unused elements. You might consider a `Diciontary<int, object>` instead.

Comment: Can you use a List to store index values as well? I thought Lists are dynamic.

Comment: Right now, this array takes 8KB. That's not a lot of memory. Allocating it right from the start will avoid reallocations and garbage objects later on.

Comment: @ThomasM with such small sizes any attempt to "optimize" will actually harm performance and memory use. A List grows by reallocating its internal buffers which leads to orphaned objects that need cleaning up. This array though is allocated once and used throughout a game. There's no need to make it dynamic

Comment: @ThomasM in fact, since you deal with tiles you probably need a 2D array

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do use a 2D array, I was just asking in a general sense

Comment: Don't do that. Details matter, especially when asking about performance at such a fine level. Which makes using `object` even worse - you'll have to cast on every single access to be able to use whatever you store there. If you store structs you'll lose the benefit of value objects, as they'll have to get boxed

Comment: Your question is poorly generalized, as your use case is very specific - a 2D array representing a game world. You're really representing a *graph data structure* with your 2D array - in this case, 2D array is the right choice - *nothing beats that structure, performance-wise* in your case - switching to `List` or `Dictionary` will be detrimental to performance in this case. The only change - figure out a type to use instead of `object` - that's the "poor practice" here! You should really re-word your question to clarify your use case.

Comment: I hate when I try to answer a question and then is it suddenly closed. This is an interesting question and there are many cases where it is is worth it to lose some memory for performance. In fact hash tables and list do some kind of this thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you're not losing performance, just a negligible amount of memory.

In fact, an array like that will be more performant than finagling smaller arrays in and out of existence, so long as you have the memory. (Each Object will be, educated guess, about 8-16 bytes.)